# Can I install a subpanel using only two ungrounded (hot) conductors and a grounding conductor?

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel

we removed the inside part of an air conditioner / heater from a mobile home. we plan to use this area as a small pantry. The wires that were connected to the heater is 2 black connected to 2 seperate breakers and a ground wire. There wasn't a white wire in the bundle. I would like to use this to add a small sub panel so that it could feed an outlet and a light switch to power light strips inside the pantry. How do you wire this to a sub panel with only 2 hot wires and a ground?

Comment: Hopefully that's 2 breakers with a tie between them?

Answer (score 3):

Without pulling an additional wire, you'd only be able to install a 240 volt subpanel.  You won't be able to install a proper 120/240V subpanel with only two ungrounded conductors and a grounding conductor.  If you want 120 volts, you'll have to pull a proper grounded (neutral) conductor.